# Ubuntu image for Raspberry Pi 4 model B

Tags: raspberrypi

As in the roadmap described ubuntu doesn't support fully the 4Gb version of raspberry. Is it resolved in the version 20.04? I found no information about it.

[ubuntu roadmap](https://ubuntu.com/blog/roadmap-for-official-support-for-the-raspberry-pi-4)

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved many weeks ago. I used 19.10 with an 4GB RPi4 from the end of March and updated a few days ago to 20.04. The system monitor shows 3.7GB available. The remainder is used as GPU memory.

Comment: Very well, thanks! I just didn't find this info anywhere.